# terraform vsphere vm slow boot

Tags: virtualization, performance

This is my first try at creating a vSphere VM using terraform. The VM does successfully create, but takes 7 mins to complete. Here are the steps I've taken.

- Manually upload an Ubuntu 16.04 ova.
- Manually convert the image to a template.
- Manually create a VM from the template through the GUI. It takes
  about 20 seconds for the VM to start.
- Create the VM using terraform pointing to the template. This takes 7 
  mins.

Using terraform the VM boot sequence progresses the same as the manually created VM and then hangs at the below message for approximately 6 and half minutes.

```
[   12.109016] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
```

The error message repeats about 6 times for both the manual and the terraform VM creation. But during the manual creation, it moves to the login prompt almost immediately. During the terraform creation, it hangs at this message for about 6 and half minutes and then moves on to the login prompt. Any idea why it is hanging during the terraform creation?

**intance.tf**

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "hellovm" {
  name = "hellovm2"
  vcpu = 1
  memory = 1024
  datacenter = "Lab09-Datacenter01"

  network_interface {
    label = "Lab09-NetA"
  }

  disk {
    template = "${var.vmtemp}"
    type = "thin"
    datastore = "${var.vmdatastore}"
  }
}
```

**terraform apply stdout**

```
Macbook12:concoursebootstrap steve$ terraform apply
vsphere_folder.concourse-base: Refreshing state... (ID: Lab09-Datacenter01/VirtualMachines)
 vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Refreshing state... (ID: hellovm)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Creating...
  datacenter:                             "" => "Lab09-Datacenter01"
  detach_unknown_disks_on_delete:         "" => "false"
  disk.#:                                 "" => "1"
  disk.3867083049.bootable:               "" => ""
  disk.3867083049.controller_type:        "" => "scsi"
  disk.3867083049.datastore:              "" => "nfs-lab09-vol1"
  disk.3867083049.iops:                   "" => ""
  disk.3867083049.keep_on_remove:         "" => ""
  disk.3867083049.key:                    "" => "<computed>"
  disk.3867083049.name:                   "" => ""
  disk.3867083049.size:                   "" => ""
  disk.3867083049.template:               "" => "ubuntu-16.04-server-cloudimg-amd64"
  disk.3867083049.type:                   "" => "thin"
  disk.3867083049.uuid:                   "" => "<computed>"
  disk.3867083049.vmdk:                   "" => ""
  domain:                                 "" => "vsphere.local"
  enable_disk_uuid:                       "" => "false"
  linked_clone:                           "" => "false"
  memory:                                 "" => "1024"
  memory_reservation:                     "" => "0"
  moid:                                   "" => "<computed>"
  name:                                   "" => "hellovm"
  network_interface.#:                    "" => "1"
  network_interface.0.ip_address:         "" => "<computed>"
  network_interface.0.ipv4_address:       "" => "<computed>"
  network_interface.0.ipv4_gateway:       "" => "<computed>"
  network_interface.0.ipv4_prefix_length: "" => "<computed>"
  network_interface.0.ipv6_address:       "" => "<computed>"
  network_interface.0.ipv6_gateway:       "" => "<computed>"
  network_interface.0.ipv6_prefix_length: "" => "<computed>"
  network_interface.0.label:              "" => "Lab09-NetA"
  network_interface.0.mac_address:        "" => "<computed>"
  network_interface.0.subnet_mask:        "" => "<computed>"
  skip_customization:                     "" => "false"
  time_zone:                              "" => "Etc/UTC"
  uuid:                                   "" => "<computed>"
  vcpu:                                   "" => "1"
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (10s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (20s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (30s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (40s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (50s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (1m0s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (1m10s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (1m20s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (1m30s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (1m40s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (1m50s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (2m0s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (2m10s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (2m20s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (2m30s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (2m40s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (2m50s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (3m0s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (3m10s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (3m20s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (3m30s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (3m40s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (3m50s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (4m0s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (4m10s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (4m20s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (4m30s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (4m40s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (4m50s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (5m0s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (5m10s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (5m20s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (5m30s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (5m40s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (5m50s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (6m0s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (6m10s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (6m20s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (6m30s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (6m40s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (6m50s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (7m0s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (7m10s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (7m20s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (7m30s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (7m40s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Creation complete (ID: hellovm)

Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

**ubuntu dmesg**

[image: ubuntu dmesg]

**terraform trace output after VM is created and it is waiting for boot**

[image: terrafrom trace output]

**The rest of the terraform output. Several minutes of repeating logs then the following**

[image: terraform trace output part 2]